# send html email asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to send `html` email that i created from gmail 3rd party plugin. I had created my own webpage for sending email. I am using `gmail smtp`. I input the following code in message body but email doesn't send as html template, simple code has been sent. Kindly help me to send html email. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected bool Sendemail()
    {
        var smtph = smtphost.Text;
        var smtpp = smtpport.Text;
        int port = Int32.Parse(smtpp);

        var smtpemail=emailsmtp.Text;
        var smtppass = passwordsmtp.Text;
        //var fromaddress = TextBox1.Text;
        var toaddress = TextBox2.Text;
        var replyto = TextBox4.Text;
        var subject = TextBox3.Text;
        var body = TextArea1.InnerText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>");
       //var textBoxText = tbDeliver.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>");

        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;



        try
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(smtpemail);
            message.To.Add(toaddress);

            message.Subject =subject;

            message.IsBodyHtml = true;  
             message.Body = "<html><body>" + body.ToString() + "</body></html>";
            //message.Body = body;
             message.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(replyto));

             SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtph, port);

             smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpemail, smtppass);
             smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
             smtpClient.Send(message);

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            throw exp;
        }
        return true;
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Sendemail();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
            this,
            this.GetType(),
            "popup",
            "alert('Email Sent Succesfully');",
            true);

    }
}
```

Following html email template i am trying to send :

```
<div class="gmail_quote gmail_extra gmail_quote">
  <blockquote class="gmail_quote" style=
  "margin:0 0 0 .8ex;border-left:1px #ccc solid;padding-left:1ex">
    <div dir="ltr">
      <div class="gmail_quote" dir="ltr">
        <div class="gmail_quote">
          <br>

          <div dir="ltr">
            <a href="https://google.com" rel="noopener" target=
            "_blank" data-saferedirecturl=
            "https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=http://rebrand.ly//secureinfo&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1519194765300000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHuqoCNs38P52qaKaNtiJt0M0yw9g">
            <img src=
            "https://www.ief.org/_resources/files/pages/logos/logos/ief-logo-with-strap-72dpi.jpg"
            alt="" width="600" height="613"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </blockquote>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: you say "simple code has been sent"... do you see the tags 'html' and 'body' in your mail body? or what you don't see is the image?

Comment: Does your body string contain the html tags, or are they escaped? In other words, if you put a breakpoint after the line 'var body=', and inspect the body variable, do you see &lt;div&gt; or <div>?

Answer (score 0):

I have replicate this scenario on my local machine. The reason it is not working on your side, that you have enclosed the code between  tags, so that is unnecessary. Remove the html tag, and directly assign html from Text Control to mail.body

```
message.body = body;
```

that will do it..

Comment: I have a functioning smtpClient MailMessage sending where I enclose the mail body within <HTML><body> and </body></HTML> tags...

Comment: @DIe I tried this, It didn't work me without that it worked perfectly fine for, I also think that tostring method on body is also causing the issue